# Javascript Ajax load on mulpiple div with different arguments

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to run the following ajax code to mulpiple divs with different values.

If I copy-paste the following code into my page, it loads only the last (or the first)

I want to run these 3 javascript calls and see 3 different result though Ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxGEOFunction(64,0);</script>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxGEOFunction(65,0);</script>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxGEOFunction(66,0);</script>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxGEOFunction(65,0);</script>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>
```

How this can be done?

Abobe  code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxGEOFunction(argId,option){
 var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

 try{
   // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
   ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }catch (e){
   // Internet Explorer Browsers
   try{
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }catch (e) {
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e){the 3 divs 
         // Something went wrong
         alert("Your browser broke!");
         return false;
      }
   }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data 
 // sent from the server and will update
 // div section in the same page.
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }
 }
 // Now get the value from user and pass it to
 // server script.


 var queryString = "?q=" + argId ;
 queryString +=  "&o=" + option;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajaxGEOInjection.php" + 
                              queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: It looks you have a race condition here

Comment: This question is tagged for "jquery", but I see no jQuery code, Are you using the jQuery library?

Comment: @JohnS  Nope. sry, I added it by accident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the three `<div>` elements unique `id` values.

```
<div id='ajaxDiv1'>foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<div id='ajaxDiv2'>foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<div id='ajaxDiv3'>foo</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
ajaxGEOFunction('ajaxDiv1',64,0);
ajaxGEOFunction('ajaxDiv2',65,0);
ajaxGEOFunction('ajaxDiv3',66,0);
</script>
```

Add a parameter to the function so you can pass the element `id`.

```
function ajaxGEOFunction(elementId,argId,option){
 ...     
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById(elementId);
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }
 }
 ...
}
```

---

If you don't want to give each div a unique `id`, and you want to be able to add divs without having to add to the JavaScript, you could give each div a `class` and use `data-*` attributes like this:

```
<div class="ajaxDiv" data-argId="64" data-option="0">foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<div class="ajaxDiv" data-argId="65" data-option="0">foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<div class="ajaxDiv" data-argId="66" data-option="0">foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<div class="ajaxDiv" data-argId="65" data-option="0">foo</div>

<script>
(function() {
    function ajaxGEOFunction(ajaxDisplay,argId,option){
        ...
         ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
             if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                 ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
             }
        }
        ...
    }

    var ajaxDisplays = document.getElementsByClassName('ajaxDiv');
    for (var i=0; i<ajaxDisplays.length; i++) {
        ajaxGEOFunction(ajaxDisplays[i],
                        ajaxDisplays[i].getAttribute('data-argId'),
                        ajaxDisplays[i].getAttribute('data-option'));
    }
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but nope. thats not an option. I can run multiple times the <div id='ajaxDiv3'>foo</div> for example in the same page.

Comment: if I am having the following this will not work.:

`<script type="text/javascript">ajaxGEOFunction(64,0);</script>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxGEOFunction(65,0);</script>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxGEOFunction(66,0);</script>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxGEOFunction(65,0);</script>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>
<hr><hr>
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxGEOFunction(64,0);</script>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>`

Comment: The multiple id issue still needs to be addressed, they need to be classes.

Comment: Man, it worked. I created a "salt" in the end of every id. E.G.
ajaxGEOFunction("somethingunique-id",64,0);

Comment: @John - I have added another option to my answer.

Comment: @EternalHour - I had written up a solution using a class before you posted your answer, but it used jQuery. It took me a while to convert it to pure JavaScript. Using a class isn't the full answer though. Looping through the elements and using `data-*` attributes are also necessary parts.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `id` for each `<div>`, how is Javascript supposed to know which `<div>` to load what? You need to use classes instead.

```
<div class='ajaxDiv'>foo</div>
```

Then, in your JS use...

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementByClassName('ajaxDiv');
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }
}
```

By using `getElementByClassName()` a NodeList will be created which AJAX can then process. Another issue you could be running into, is that AJAX is asynchronous. You may also try experimenting with using synchronous requests instead.

```
var queryString = "?q=" + argId ;
queryString +=  "&o=" + option;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajaxGEOInjection.php" + 
                              queryString, false); //process as synchronous//
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```